# Getting the key of the only element in a PHP array

Tags: php, associative-array

The key of the associative array is dynamically generated. How do I get the "Key" of such an array?

```
$arr = array ('dynamic_key' => 'Value');
```

I am aware that It is possible to access it through a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) echo "Key value is $key";
```

However, I know that this array will have only one key and want to avoid a foreach loop.  Is it possible to access the value of this element in any other way? Or get the key name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

edit: http://php.net/each says:

> each

**Warning** This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

---

Using [key()](http://docs.php.net/key) is fine.
If you're going to fetch the value anyway you can also use [each()](http://php.net/each) and [list()](http://php.net/list).

```
$arr = array ('dynamic_key' => 'Value');
list($key, $value) = each($arr);
echo $key, ' -> ', $value, "\n";
```

prints `dynamic_key -> Value`

Comment: A little mistake. Last line should be: `echo $key. ' -> '. $value. "\n";` instead of `echo $key, ' -> ', $value, "\n";` (dots, not comas).

Comment: PolGraphic: "Last line should be" - no, it shouldn't. No need to do a concatenation there. You can pass a virtually unlimited number of comma-separated arguments to echo.

Comment: `each()` is deprecated in newer versions of PHP, so... Don't rely on this working in the future.

Answer (score 9):

Shortest, easiest and most independent solution is:

```
$key   = key($arr);
$value = reset($arr);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
echo $keys[0];
```

Or use `array_values()` for the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_shift(array_keys($arr))` (with `array_values` for getting the value), but it still does a loop internally.

Answer (score 0):

What about array_keys()?

It does return an array though...

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that you have the value of entry and want to get the key ?

```
array_search ($value, $array)
```

> Returns the key for needle if it is
>   found in the array, FALSE otherwise.
>
> If needle is found in haystack more
>   than once, the first matching key is
>   returned. To return the keys for all
>   matching values, use array_keys() with
>   the optional search_value parameter
>   instead.

more details :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php